# Why is the Recovery HD mounted when running Software Update?

Tags: software-update, recovery-hd

I have installed HardwareGrowler, which displays a notification every time something is being mounted/ejected, connected/disconnected, etc.

It tells me that at the start of when Software Update the Recovery HD is mounted and after something like 5 seconds it is ejected.

Is this because it needs to check the version of your Recovery HD, or is it used for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software Update checks and updates both your running Lion and your recovery partition, so that in the event of a significant security issue booting to the recovery partition won't instantly open you up to attack.  (Compare booting unpatched Windows XP from DVD or a vendor recovery partition for recovery purposes; it has severe security issues fixed by service packs.  I'm not picking on Windows here; XP's quite old at this point, and was the biggest target out there for years, and security is a rapidly moving target.)  Given the recent growth in Mac malware, this is a good thing.